# Error en formSubmit

Tags: html

estoy practicando con un formulario y quiero que funcione a través de formSubmit.
Ya verifiqué el mail y cree una página personalizada de Thank You.
Cuando submito el form aparece la página para chequear el captcha y cuando la chequeo en lugar de ir a la página de Thank you, aparece una página diciendo que hay un error:

"Make sure your form has the method="POST" attribute"

No entiendo por qué, ya que en mi form tengo:
`<form action="https://formsubmit.co/mimail@gmail.com" method="POST">`

Y aunque me da ese mensaje de error, el mensaje que envío a través del form llega bien a mi casilla de mail. Pero necesito que se vea bien y vaya a la página de Thank you.

Se les ocurre por qué puedo tener este problema?

Comment: Te sugiero que les preguntes a los administradores de la web de formsubmit.co.  Debe ser un bug de ellos, no tuyo.

Comment: @masterguru ya encontré el problema. Para ir a la página de thank you había puesto una ruta relativa y tenía que ser la url. Gracias.

Comment: Vaya, me alegro pues :-) ... la próxima vez recuerda incluir todo el código que estes usando para que podamos verlo también, pues eso debe estar en los parámetros que le diste al formulario en forma de `name` supongo.

Answer (score 0):

A mí me pasó lo mismo.

Para arreglar ese error al final del formulario (dentro de la etiqueta `<form>`) tienes que agregar la siguiente línea:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://francocarreras.com/index.html">
```

En este caso yo tengo este link (https://francocarreras.com/index.html) que es el inicio de mi portfolio, pero en tu caso tienes que poner el link de la web a la que desees redirigir a los usuarios, eso sí, SIEMPRE con el `https://` al inicio del link, si no ahí es cuando sucede el error y aparece el mensaje:

> "Make sure your form has the method="POST" attribute"